# how to change value after controller in spring RESTful

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want change data after `@RestController` class in Spring

I need to change the fields data based on the specified language.

example:

enum:

```
public enum Gender {
    WOMAN, MAN, OTHER
}
```

the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public User get(@PathVariable Long id) throws Exception {

    log.debug("Entering get( id={} )", id);

    User user = null;

    try {
        user = UserService.get(id);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.debug("Error occurred in get().", e);

        throw e;
    }

    return user;
}
```

this output:

```
{
    fisrtName: 'john',
    lastName: 'doe',
    gender: 'man'
}
```

change to this output:

```
{
    fisrtName: 'john',
    lastName: 'doe',
    gender: 'homme'
}
```

Comment: You say, "change ... based on the specified language"... Who specifies the language? Where exactly is it specified? Answering this questions might lead to a better solution.

Comment: hi  @MarkBramnik, ofcourse . client can change language (En, france, ...)

Answer (score 1):

I assume user.gender is a enum. Then you could add a custom Serializer and Deserializer to your JSON Mapper (hopefully Jackson).

```
@JsonComponent
public class TranslatedGenderJsonComponent {

   public static class TranslatedGenderSerializer extends StdSerializer<Gender> {
        
        public TranslatedGenderSerializer () {
            super(Gender.class);
        }
    
        public void serialize(
          Gender gender, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) 
          throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    
            String translatedGender = myTranslateFunction(gender);
    
            generator.writeString(translatedGender );
        }
    }   

    public static class TranslatedGenderDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Gender> {
        
        public TranslatedGenderDeserializer () {
            super(Gender.class);
        }
    
       public Gender deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
          throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

            JsonToken currentToken = jp.getCurrentToken();      
            if (currentToken.equals(JsonToken.VALUE_STRING)) {             
                String text jp.getText().trim();
                Gender gender = myInverseTranslateFunction(text);
                return gender;
            } else if (currentToken.equals(JsonToken.VALUE_NULL)) {
                return getNullValue();
            } else {        
                throw ctxt.mappingException(Gender.class);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*This code is not tested, it is just written in the browser! (I am quite unsure with the deserializer/parser code.) But I hope it will guide you to a solution.*

Comment: thanks vary much,  @JsonComponent used in spring boot but I can't use. I use from Spring non boot

Comment: mohammad_soleimani: you can use the same approach, but you need to register the Serializer/Deserializer by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I changed code:

the controller:

```
@Autowired
GlobalMassengerAdvice globalMassenger;

@RequestMapping(value = "/get/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public User get(@PathVariable Long id) throws Exception {

    log.debug("Entering get( id={} )", id);

    User user = null;

    try {
        user = userService.get(id);
        
        String value = globalMassenger.getMessage(user.getGender().name());
        
        user.setGender( value );

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.debug("Error occurred in get().", e);

        throw e;
    }

    return user;
}
```

I add new Class (GlobalMassengerAdvice):

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalMassengerAdvice {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;
    
    public String getMessage(final String messageKey, final Object... messageParameters) {
        Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        String result = null;
        try {
            result = messageSource.getMessage(messageKey, messageParameters, locale);
        } catch (NoSuchMessageException e) {
            result = messageKey;
        }
        return result;
    }
    
}
```